# INSERT conflicted with foreign key - SQL Server bug?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

UPDATE: the issue does not happen when run against SQL Server 2008. So this is something strange (or wrong) with SQL Server 2000.

I try to do a simple insert on SQL Server 2000:

```
INSERT INTO UserAddresses (UserId, AddressId)
  SELECT UserId, Id
  FROM Addresses
```

and I get this:

> INSERT statement conflicted with
>   COLUMN FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK569ABB5045EE0940'. The conflict
>   occurred in database 'Orders', table
>   'Addresses', column 'Id'.

I'm well aware of what this means, but I can't understand why conflict happens - notice that I insert IDs from the Addresses table, so they DO exist! Why can't SQL Server find them on the foreign key end in the Addresses table? Should I do silly

```
SELECT * FROM Addresses 
WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM Addresses)
```

or what?

Some more info: the IDs are GUIDs, data comes from the legacy DB (import). First I populate Addresses, then try to insert into UserAddresses. If I do SELECT TOP 100 ... it works... so it's a problem with some record but I can't understand why it happens.

```
CREATE TABLE [Addresses] (
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL ,
     PRIMARY KEY  CLUSTERED ([Id])  ON [PRIMARY] ,
) ON [PRIMARY]
CREATE TABLE [Users] (
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL ,
     PRIMARY KEY  CLUSTERED ([Id])  ON [PRIMARY] 
) ON [PRIMARY]
CREATE TABLE [UserAddresses] (
    [UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL ,
    [AddressId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL ,
    CONSTRAINT [FK569ABB5045EE0940] FOREIGN KEY 
    (
        [AddressId]
    ) REFERENCES [Addresses] (
        [Id]
    ),
    CONSTRAINT [UserAddressesToAddressFK] FOREIGN KEY 
    (
        [UserId]
    ) REFERENCES [Users] (
        [Id]
    )
) ON [PRIMARY]
ALTER TABLE Addresses ADD UserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
INSERT INTO Addresses (UserId, Id)
SELECT legacy_userid, legacy_single_useraddressid -- both are guids
FROM LegacyUsers INNER JOIN LegacyAddresses
```

UPDATE: I've just done this without errors (query batch completed):

```
DECLARE c CURSOR FOR SELECT UserId, Id FROM Addresses
OPEN c
DECLARE @uid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, @aid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @uid, @aid
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
   PRINT @aid
   INSERT INTO UserAddresses (UserId, AddressId)
   VALUES (@uid, @aid)
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @uid, @aid
END
CLOSE c
DEALLOCATE c
```

I wonder why INSERT fails while foreach cursor works...

UPDATE: oops, after cursor completed, INSERT works, too. But it never works standalone. Here's what I do:

1. Run the import script so that it populates Addresses table
2. Manually run INSERT - it fails
3. Manually run CURSOR - it works
4. DELETE FROM UserAddresses
5. Manually run INSERT - it works now

Is it a magic or I'm a complete idiot missing something?

UPDATE: If I do

```
ALTER TABLE UserAddresses DROP CONSTRAINT FK569ABB5045EE0940

INSERT INTO UserAddresses (UserId, AddressId)
SELECT UserId, Id
FROM Addresses

    alter table UserAddresses 
        add constraint FK569ABB5045EE0940
        foreign key (AddressId) 
        references Addresses
```

it also works. I think it's a bug in SQL Server 2000 despite the "never blame the compiler" rule.

Comment: What is the definition of the UserAddresses table ?

Comment: maybe you want to name your constraints a bit more intuitively than `CONSTRAINT [FK569ABB5045EE0940] ` - how about `CONSTRAINT FK_UserAddresses_Addresses` or so?

Comment: Are you sure that I name my constraints FK569ABB5045EE0940 by typing the name? ;-) This is done by ORM, and as you can see above even with that I do name them UserAddressesToAddressFK, only that it doesn't work the inverse way (FluentNHibernate limitation I suppose, have to find out). Anyway, I don't see how this will help.

Comment: The only thing I could think of would be that some of your guid are not in a format recognized by MSSQL but it's a long shot as it does not explain why your second 1 to 5 sequence works...

Comment: @Locksfree: the columns are defined as GUID with an FK. So it's very unlikely

Answer (score 1):

### Update - The "harry" Schema

gbn commented that this could be a schema issue. I updated my original code example and was able to get (almost*) the exact error.

> (* Note that I'm running this on 2008 and the OP is running on 2000. SQL 2008 schema-qualifies the table in the error message.)

### Updated Code - The "harry" Schema

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO
--<< ========================== DROPS ==========================
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#UserGUIDs') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #UserGUIDs
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#AddressGUIDs') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #AddressGUIDs
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE [id] = OBJECT_ID('UserAddresses'))
    DROP TABLE [UserAddresses]
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE [id] = OBJECT_ID('Users'))
    DROP TABLE [Users]
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE [id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.Addresses'))
    DROP TABLE dbo.[Addresses]
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE [id] = OBJECT_ID('harry.Addresses'))
    DROP TABLE harry.[Addresses]
GO

--<< ========================== TABLES ==========================
--<< Users
CREATE TABLE [Users] (
    [Id]        uniqueidentifier  NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWID()  PRIMARY KEY,
    [UserName]  varchar(10)       NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

--<< Addresses
CREATE TABLE harry.[Addresses] (
    [Id]        uniqueidentifier  NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWID()  PRIMARY KEY,
    [Address1]  varchar(20)       NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.[Addresses] (
    [Id]        uniqueidentifier  NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWID()  PRIMARY KEY,
    [Address1]  varchar(20)       NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

--<< UserAddresses
CREATE TABLE [UserAddresses] (
    [UserId]    uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    [AddressId] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [FK569ABB5045EE0940]       FOREIGN KEY ([AddressId]) REFERENCES [Addresses] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [UserAddressesToAddressFK] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId])    REFERENCES [Users] ([Id])
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

--<< ========================== DATA ==========================
--<< Populate Users
CREATE TABLE #UserGUIDs ([UserId] uniqueidentifier)
GO
INSERT INTO [Users] ([UserName]) VALUES ('UserName1')
INSERT INTO [Users] ([UserName]) VALUES ('UserName2')
INSERT INTO [Users] ([UserName]) VALUES ('UserName3')
INSERT INTO [Users] ([UserName]) VALUES ('UserName4')
GO
INSERT INTO #UserGUIDs ([UserId]) SELECT [Id] FROM [Users]
GO

--<< Populate Addresses
CREATE TABLE #AddressGUIDs ([AddressId] uniqueidentifier)
GO
INSERT INTO harry.[Addresses] ([Address1]) VALUES ('1234 First Street')
INSERT INTO harry.[Addresses] ([Address1]) VALUES ('2345 Second Street')
INSERT INTO harry.[Addresses] ([Address1]) VALUES ('3456 Third Street')
INSERT INTO harry.[Addresses] ([Address1]) VALUES ('4567 Fourth Street')
GO
INSERT INTO #AddressGUIDs ([AddressId]) SELECT [Id] FROM harry.[Addresses]
GO

PRINT 'Users'
SELECT * FROM [Users]
PRINT 'Addresses'
SELECT * FROM harry.[Addresses]
GO

--<< ========================== TEST ==========================
--<< Populate UserAddresses
INSERT INTO UserAddresses (UserId, AddressId)
SELECT
    u.Id, -- UserID
    a.Id  -- AddressID
FROM harry.Addresses   AS a
CROSS JOIN Users AS u
GO

PRINT 'UserAddresses'
SELECT * FROM [UserAddresses]
GO
```

### Result

```
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 4
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK569ABB5045EE0940". The conflict occurred in database "RGTest1", table "dbo.Addresses", column 'Id'.
```

---

### Original Post

queen3, here is a complete working example of what I *think* you're attempting. I tried to make it SQL 2000-compatible, but I only have 2005 and 2008 available.

Please create a new database and run this script. If it does not duplicate what you're trying to do, please explain or just post modified code.

This script works as-is, but I'm sure there is something that is different from your application.

Rob

### Code

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO
--<< ========================== DROPS ==========================
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#UserGUIDs') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #UserGUIDs
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#AddressGUIDs') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #AddressGUIDs
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE [id] = OBJECT_ID('UserAddresses'))
    DROP TABLE [UserAddresses]
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE [id] = OBJECT_ID('Users'))
    DROP TABLE [Users]
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE [id] = OBJECT_ID('Addresses'))
    DROP TABLE [Addresses]
GO

--<< ========================== TABLES ==========================
--<< Users
CREATE TABLE [Users] (
    [Id]        uniqueidentifier  NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWID()  PRIMARY KEY,
    [UserName]  varchar(10)       NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

--<< Addresses
CREATE TABLE [Addresses] (
    [Id]        uniqueidentifier  NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWID()  PRIMARY KEY,
    [Address1]  varchar(20)       NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

--<< UserAddresses
CREATE TABLE [UserAddresses] (
    [UserId]    uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    [AddressId] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [FK569ABB5045EE0940]       FOREIGN KEY ([AddressId]) REFERENCES [Addresses] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [UserAddressesToAddressFK] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId])    REFERENCES [Users] ([Id])
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

--<< ========================== DATA ==========================
--<< Populate Users
CREATE TABLE #UserGUIDs ([UserId] uniqueidentifier)
GO
INSERT INTO [Users] ([UserName]) VALUES ('UserName1')
INSERT INTO [Users] ([UserName]) VALUES ('UserName2')
INSERT INTO [Users] ([UserName]) VALUES ('UserName3')
INSERT INTO [Users] ([UserName]) VALUES ('UserName4')
GO
INSERT INTO #UserGUIDs ([UserId]) SELECT [Id] FROM [Users]
GO

--<< Populate Addresses
CREATE TABLE #AddressGUIDs ([AddressId] uniqueidentifier)
GO
INSERT INTO [Addresses] ([Address1]) VALUES ('1234 First Street')
INSERT INTO [Addresses] ([Address1]) VALUES ('2345 Second Street')
INSERT INTO [Addresses] ([Address1]) VALUES ('3456 Third Street')
INSERT INTO [Addresses] ([Address1]) VALUES ('4567 Fourth Street')
GO
INSERT INTO #AddressGUIDs ([AddressId]) SELECT [Id] FROM [Addresses]
GO

PRINT 'Users'
SELECT * FROM [Users]
PRINT 'Addresses'
SELECT * FROM [Addresses]
GO

--<< ========================== TEST ==========================
--<< Populate UserAddresses
INSERT INTO UserAddresses (UserId, AddressId)
SELECT
    u.Id, -- UserID
    a.Id  -- AddressID
FROM Addresses   AS a
CROSS JOIN Users AS u
GO

PRINT 'UserAddresses'
SELECT * FROM [UserAddresses]
GO
```

Comment: If you find that it fails on SQL 2000 (which I suspect it won't), try it on SQL 2005 or 2008 also to see if there is a difference. I created and tested the script using 2008.

Comment: I can see why it fails for two tables with different users, but there's only one user in my DB. And it doesn't fail if I apply FK afterwards for me. As for your original test, it doesn't fail for me, and I can't test on 2005/8 because I don't have them installed. I'll post more details on what I do but I still think it's a problem with big-batch insert, because it works in 1-by-1 cursor, in TOP 1/100, and when FK is applied afterwards. So it's not a problem with the data or schema. Nevertheless, thanks for such a detailed investigation.

Comment: I've added more details on tables and how I populate Addresses. Not that I think it will help... Currently I'm fine with DROP/ADD CONSTRAINT so this question remains only for curiosity. Just a weird bug that I don't and would like to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Random thought...

What credentials are you using, what did ORM use, and what schema?

eg the tables and FKs are actually using "bob" schema

- bob.Addresses
- bob.Users
- bob.UserAddresses

but because of pre-SQL 2005 user/schema stuff, you are in "harry" schema...

```
INSERT INTO UserAddresses (UserId, AddressId)
  SELECT UserId, Id
  FROM Addresses

-- is actually
INSERT INTO harry.UserAddresses (UserId, AddressId)
  SELECT UserId, Id
  FROM bob.Addresses
-- or
INSERT INTO bob.UserAddresses (UserId, AddressId)
  SELECT UserId, Id
  FROM harry.Addresses
```

More than once I've enjoyed the spectacle of testers and developers getting different results because of lack of qualifying schema...

Comment: Good point. I had "de-schema-fied" my test code. Check out the update to my post.

Answer (score -1):

Check the UserAddresses table.  Maybe someone has defined a (BAD!) trigger on the table that does some Evil to the Addresses or UserAddresses table somehow.

Comment: The whole database is generated by ORM (NHibernate) just before I do import. It is completely innocent, even without data.

Comment: Trigger are good not bad, they are only bad if the developer is too uneducated to use them properly.

Comment: Triggers can be good, or they can be "bad".  An example of a Bad Trigger would be one that modifies your UserAddresses or Addresses table in some evil way that is not transparent.  That's what I meant.